# How to check if PartnerData is null (Dynamic object)

Tags: c#, axapta

I want to check if a specific item in PartnerData is null or not.

Dynamic Object - Dynamic objects expose members such as properties and methods at run time, instead of in at compile time.

Below is my snippet

```
item.PartnerData.itemVoid
```

I want to check if PartnerData has itemVoid. When I do like item.PartnerData.itemVoid.Equals(null) it throws an error, maybe because this is not the right thing to check if itemVoid is null or what. Base from what I know PartnerData will be resolved at runtime.

Can I check if a PartnerData has this specific items like itemVoid etc.? Or there is a safe way to access the itemVoid without throwing an error like *System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' does not contain a definition for **itemVoid***

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is `PartnerData`?

Comment: PartnerData is a dynamic object

Comment: "Dynamic objects expose members such as properties and methods at run time, instead of in at compile time."

Comment: try if(item?.PartnerData==null || item.PartnerData.itemVoid)

Comment: if.PartnerData == null works but accessing item.PartnerData.itemVoid throws an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp

Comment: if item.PartnerData == null returns true then but obvious it will not have **itemVoid** property in it. If it returns false then and only then get **itemVoid** value